# How to convert BSON to JSON with human-readable date format

Tags: json, mongodb, date, bson

I would like to transform a BSON dump of MongoDB to JSON.

To do that, I'm using the [bsondump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/bsondump/) tool provided with Mongo, but I get an output like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "5316d194b34f6a0c8776e187" ), "begin_date" : Date( 1394004372038 ), "foo" : "bar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "5316d198b34f6a0c8776e188" ), "begin_date" : Date( 1394004407696 ), "foo" : "bar" }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the dates appear in a human readable format (e.g. `hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy`) ?

**Edit**

It looks like that a more recent version of mongodump outputs dates as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "5316d194b34f6a0c8776e187" ), "begin_date" : {"$date":"2015-11-11T08:45:03.974Z"}}, "foo" : "bar" }
```

So this question is not relevant anymore.
Thanks everybody for your help here.

Comment: Too broad. What is your implementation language?

Comment: Just using command line. My purpose is to analyse the content of the dump.

Comment: Well for the layman that means JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, try mongoexport instead. You should get a form out of that which is a little more convertible.

Comment: How about display using find() command?

Comment: Actually, mongoexport still outputs timestamps instead of "human" dates.

Comment: Displaying with find() works (meaning I also have to import the BSON file into my database, which is a bit annoying). However, for a big table, this is not convenient at all !

Comment: If your intention is to analyse the data then you can try [some online bson to json converters like this](https://json-bson-converter.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 66):

> bsondump converts BSON files into human-readable formats,
>   including JSON. For example, bsondump is useful for reading the output
>   files generated by mongodump.

Source:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/bsondump

**Examples**

```
bsondump --outFile collection.json collection.bson
```

The `--pretty` option outputs documents in a pretty-printed format JSON, eg:

```
bsondump --pretty --outFile collection.json collection.bson
```

Answer (score 21):

To create a JSON file directly from the database, use [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/)

```
mongoexport --db myDatabase --collection myCollection --jsonArray --out myJsonFile.json
```

Comment: Same, the date format is { "$date" : 1397141347767 }

Comment: @vcarel when I do a `db.test.insert({"begin_date" : Date( 1394004372038 ), "foo" : "bar" })` and then `[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "540bfc4d6b29db6430fcd93e" }, "begin_date" : "Sun Sep 07 2014 08:33:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "foo" : "bar" }]` I get: `[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "540bfc4d6b29db6430fcd93e" }, "begin_date" : "Sun Sep 07 2014 08:33:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "foo" : "bar" }]` in test.json

Comment: Apparently, Date(something) returns the current time as a string. If you try new Date(1394004372038) you'll get in the export "begin_date" : { "$date" : 1394004372038 }

Answer (score -3):

```
db.players.find({"name" : "John"}).forEach(printjson);
```